# Console App to start a CodedUI test

Tags: c#, testing, dll, batch-file, coded-ui-tests

I have a coded ui test that I want to start by using batch, its a .dll file.

The reason I'm calling it from a batch file is that the server has to be restarted before this test can be carried out.

Is it just a simple `call test.dll` or do I have to do other stuff?

**Update** *Code Found*

```
Playback.Initialize();
TestProject.CodedUITest1 coded = new TestProject.CodedUITest1();
coded.CodedUITestMethod1();
Playback.Cleanup();
```

Take from [Here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2010/07/15/running-codedui-test-from-another-application.aspx), Its missing two reference addings from the private assemblies:

1. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Uia.dll
2. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.IE.dll

Hope this helps other people looking to do this

Comment: You can't run DLLs like you do an executable program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run a Dll file like you can an exe. A Dll contains code intended to be used by a program, it means one source of code can be used by many programs, which saves duplicating the code.

Usually the Dll will have documented functions you can call via a program, unless you built it yourself in which case you would know :)

Try and find the program that uses the Dll and call that, or find the docs for it and run the function from `rundll32` as @PA. suggested.

Comment: I built/will be building it myself, coded ui test to open and start a program after the machine is restarted.

Comment: What language is this coded in? The solution to this will be largely dependant on that.

Comment: Then you won't be able to use `rundll32` as a C# Dll is not a *real* Dll. Did you make the Dll too?

Comment: I'm not sure if I did. I wrote the code and there is a .dll in the debug folder. Is there anyway to call it so?

Comment: You must have created a DLL project then. Is the DLL named the same as your project? If so then create a console app, then you can add a reference to the DLL, and access using `DLLName.DLLClass.DLLMethod();`

Comment: I created the project by creating a coded ui test project. It has the same name as the project. Do I replace the `DLLName` to the name of the project?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13847/discussion-between-bali-c-and-elsheepo)

Answer (score 0):

DLLs are *dynamic libraries* that need to be linked and called from an application program. Every DLL has its own exported interface, or collection of entry points to be called from the external executable, or, may be, from another DLL.

Windows provides a set of calls to help caller programs to load, detect entry points, and unload DLLs. Beyond this limited common functionality, there are endless combinations of ways of using a DLL, in the calling conventions, in the ways of passing parameters, in the types of the parameters, in the ways of returning data, in the ways of synchronizing, notifying events, interrupting, multithreading, in almost every aspect of programming models.

Having said so, it is possible that your DLL is expected to be called from some specific application program, and thus is possibly following and strict and well defined API. One such type of DLLs are Windows System DLLs that are intended to be run with **rundll** executable program. `rundll32.exe` is the Windows system executable that launches and invokes functions that are packed and shipped in .dll files, from a DLL that is explicitely programmed to be called this way.

to invoke your TestFunction inside your TEST.DLL, passing 1234 as a parameter, you'd use

```
RUNDLL32  TEST.DLL, TestFunction 1234
```

Rundll will perform for you the following tasks

- Load TEST.DLL via LoadLibrary().
- Address the TestFunction function via GetProcAddress().
- Call TestFunction function, passing the rest of the command line
- Unload the DLL and exit.

Comment: So instead of `call test.dll` I use `RUNDLL TEST.DLL` to start my test, A coded ui ?