# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I'm trying write a console application that will run my coded ui test using 
2013 visual studio premium.

The full error message I'm getting is:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

My code for the console application is pretty simple:

```
using Demo;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension;
using Keyboard = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Keyboard;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
//namespace demo
{

    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Playback.Initialize();
            Demo.CodedUITest1 cd = new Demo.CodedUITest1();
            cd.CodedUITestMethod1();
            Playback.Cleanup();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing coded UI test from a standalone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482796/executing-coded-ui-test-from-a-standalone-application)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469323/console-app-to-start-a-codedui-test or of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482796/executing-coded-ui-test-from-a-standalone-application